# Best way to preview page of Pdf file in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialog, pdfrenderer

I'm developing a feature to preview the pages of a Pdf file in Android.
I tried with **PdfRenderer** using the recyclerview to show the list page, and the problem is it causes lag in the app.

My question is: What's the best way to preview the pages of a Pdf file? , or can my code improve anything to avoid lag?

Here's my code:

Create a renderer in the activity

```
val fileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor?
fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(
    File(path),
    ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY
)
if (fileDescriptor != null) {
    renderer = PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor)
}
```

Pass renderer into a DiaLog

```
val splitPageSelectDialog = SplitPageSelectDialog(this, numberPage, renderer) {
}
```

Pass renderer into an Adapter

```
mAdapter = new PageAdapter(getContext(), mOptionList, renderer, this);
}
```

And bind data in ViewHolder

```
val page = renderer.openPage(position)
val width = page.width
val height = page.height
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)
page.close()
binding.imgPreviewPage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Finally, I got something like this:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Q8L.jpg)

Can anyone help me here?